# How can I get my location without adding Map fragment on Activity in android?

Tags: java, android, gps, android-service, android-location

I got location permission and made service , however I don't know how to get My Location from service without adding Map fragment.
I need to get my location and set Text on my TextView. //I don't need to get fragment at this activity
do I need to use post method in TextView? and How can I get Location from Service?
Please Help me! thanks

this is my MainActivity.java extends PermissionActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
    switch (compoundButton.getId()) {
        case R.id.locationSwitch:
            Constants.checkFineLocationPermission(MainActivity.this);
            if(compoundButton.isChecked()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationService.class);
                startService(intent);
            }else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationService.class);
                stopService(intent);
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

and this is PermissionActivity.

```
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[],int[] grantResults){
        switch (requestCode){
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION:{
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),getClass());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else{
                    // Log.d("Permission always denyed");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                            .setData(Uri.parse("package:"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

and this is service

```
private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
{
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need map, just use LocationManager to get the location ?

Comment: I mean LocationManager's instance is exist on my service and I don't know how can I access that instance.. can I get that one with getter method?

Comment: and what kind of method do i need at that class?  I need to get detail location like city, street, etc

Comment: if its in service, use broad cast receiver in order to get the updated location from activity

Comment: oh.. than I need to study about borad cast receiver! thank you a lot:)

Comment: You cant get city, street from location manager, all you get is geo point(45.22655.., 2.66565...) , there are several public apis to convert geo-point readable address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Google Fused Location Service. It's provides most accurate position. Take a tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html). So basically just put this stuff into service.

Comment: thanks I did it with your URL and I didn't know even it is exist :)

Comment: @J.ho glad to help :)